# ingesting millions of telemetry events per day - Redis vs kafka vs another queue/message broker my best best for ingestion

Tags: node.js, express, redis, microservices

I will shortly be ingesting millions of telemetry events per day. It is important that we don't lose these telemetry events as they represent events like sales which is used for billing and charging customers. Today we are at tens of thousands of events per day but expect to 100x in the coming months.

Today we simply have a rest endpoint where clients send us telemetry events as POST requests. The service that hosts the endpoint (node express) has some logic which detects the telemetry payload type and performs actions based off that (e.g. write to database, send an sms).

What I am thinking would be nice is to have a FIFO queue which a very lightweight REST API(s) can push telemetry events into, then have a horizontally scalable bunch of microservices which pull telemetry and can perform the appropriate action from there*. A telemetry event should only be processed/consumed once by a single service.

So my question now falls to, what technology(s) should I choose? Loosing a telemetry event is a pretty big deal. At this point in time, when the clients sending us telemetry events receive a HTTP 200 (successful) from our system (saying we received it) we have no way of ever getting them to send us telemetry again - i.e. once we receive a telemetry event we must not lose it.  Further reading and processing a telemetry event more than once is also a terrible thing to do.

From reading the REDIS docs it seems I can simply use the FIFO queue - push and pop operations are atomic, so this looks good. What I am concerned about is:  (i) would all my microservices workers that process the telemetry events need to be continuously polling the redis queue, or can it be more event driven (notification of a new queue item)  (ii) my other points of failure - redis going down (AOF file can help) or things I haven’t thought about yet  (iii) how would this queue scale if we started handling more amount of data as the queue seems to be a choke point (can you shard the queue or would one just use kafka or maybe something like rsmq**?)

EDIT: A reason I'm particularly interested in redis is I have other needs for it - caching database queryies/tables, expiring keys for a notification service.

Thank you

*I could even perhaps have different queues for each type of telemetry.

**http://smrchy.github.io/rsmq/

Comment: Interested in what other responses you get. If you expect to handle millions of events per day, an SQS queue would work fine. You can use redis to lock messages to ensure duplicate delivery isn't processed. An ESM can be placed on the SQS queue to deliver messages from the queue to lambda horizontally. You may try direct delivery to SNS first and let SNS actually deliver the message to your SQS queue (this doesn't cost extra). This should work up to hundreds of millions of events per day. Once you get into the billions YMMV.

Comment: Seems to me you are dealing with real-time telemetry data, thus kinesis should be first thing to consider. You haven't mentioned it at all, thus not sure if you already removed it from the equation?

Comment: out of interets, why doesn't anyone recommend SQS FIFO?

Comment: @Prof SQS FIFO always comes with overhead that makes it difficult to do in a highly distributed way. It guarantees order and exactly once delivery at a cost that should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to recommend a replicated log (Kafka, Pulsar, and Kinesis come to mind), as they'll tend to give you stronger durability guarantees and provide a clear path to scaling out (though if you care about event ordering, scaling Kafka entails some subtle gotchas).  Durability after consumption also enables later remixes of the events.

In general in a distributed system (which is what you're building) you can have at-least-once or at-most-once processing.  Exactly-once (at least in its hard, true sense) is sufficiently difficult that it generally makes more sense to go for effectively-once: at-least-once with idempotence so if the same event is processed twice, the effects only happen once (when Confluent or the Flink folks talk about exactly-once they're more properly talking about "effectively-once(-with-some-caveats)").

The note about at-least-once vs. at-most-once applies even if your queue's enqueue/dequeue operations are atomic.  Consider a task like "dequeue event and authorize credit card".  Your queue might allow you to bundle the authorization into the dequeue transaction, so it's

1. Begin dequeue transaction
2. Authorize credit card
3. Complete transaction

A network condition, process crash, etc. happens during 2.  Did the authorization go through?  Eventually the transaction fails and the message is still in the queue, so it gets picked up again (at-least-once) and the authorization happens.  Eventually you find out whether it happened twice (I'm ignoring for the sake of argument that the credit card networks can dedupe double auth).  Alternatively, you can take the at-most-once approach and complete the dequeue before authorizing the card.

It may be worth reading up on the saga pattern.